# File Descriptors closing in forked subprocesses in Python

Tags: python, multiprocessing, fork

In a Python 3.8 application a parent process is responsible for creating child processes (workers) and forwarding messages to them via IPC (tasks).

Parent process has its own logger that uses FileHandler to write to a file `main.log` but it also opens one logger per child process with a unique file for each of them to log IPC activity and errors.

Child processes are created via system call fork. IPC is done via OS queues. See below diagram that illustrates the situation.

[image: childprocesses]

The problem: while it is beneficial to log IPC activity on the parent process side and keep it in a dedicated file, this opens a lot of File Descriptors (FDs) which are all inherited by each and every subsequent child process.

Question: how to manage these FDs? Manually find and close them in each child process on run()? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass `close_fds=True` to whatever function (e.g. `run`) you are using for starting a subprocess:

> If close_fds is true, all file descriptors except 0, 1 and 2 will be
> closed before the child process is executed. Otherwise when close_fds
> is false, file descriptors obey their inheritable flag as described in
> Inheritance of File Descriptors.

Source: https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen

Answer (score 1):

Set the close-on-exec flag for those file descriptors you don't want to carry over to the child processes. Either by setting the `O_CLOEXEC` flag upon opening, or later with `fcntl` set `FD_CLOEXEC`.

Before you ask, `O_CLOEXEC != FD_CLOEXEC`.

Comment: This is a noop unless there is an exec after the fork, which may or may not be the case for the OP.

Comment: @pts: There's only very rare cases, that rely on narrowly defined circumstances where a `fork` *is not* followed by an `exec`. Strictly speaking, if you don't follow an `fork` with an `exec` most likely that program is badly broken. – The narrow circumstance in which you can fork without exec is: 1) Your program is linked statically and doesn't create threads. 2) the forked off childs are short lived, do not call any 3rd party library (including libc) functions and limit their use of syscalls to the signal safe ones. Anything else is a bug. Also see `vfork`, which has even stronger caveats.